# Compiler asking for lifetime in struct when lifetime is given

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm trying to write the examples in the book "SFML Game Development" but I'm having a problem with the lifetimes for the struct that's supposed to represent the game world. The error is as follows:

```
extern crate sfml;

use self::sfml::window::*;
use self::sfml::graphics::*;

pub struct Game<'s> {
    mWindow: RenderWindow,
    mPlayer: &'s CircleShape,
}
```

Error message:

```
error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
 --> src/game.rs:8:18
  |
8 |     mPlayer: &'s CircleShape,
  |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^ expected lifetime parameter
```

Why is it asking for a lifetime if I have given it one?

Comment: See also [How do I fix a missing lifetime specifier?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43330616/155423)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is it asking for a lifetime if I have given it one?

Because you haven't given it the lifetime where it's needed. Look closely at the error message. It's telling you that `CircleShape` is missing a lifetime, not the *reference* to `CircleShape` (although that's also needed).

Review the definition of `CircleShape`:

```
pub struct CircleShape<'s> { /* fields omitted */ }
```

It has been parameterized by a lifetime, so you need to provide one:

```
pub struct Game<'s> {
    mWindow: RenderWindow,
    mPlayer: &'s CircleShape<'s>,
}
```

Whether that's *correct* for your case, I can't say, but it should compile.