# Missing lifetime specifier in returned HashMap<&i32, SimpleCallback>

Tags: rust

Consider the following:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::vec::Vec;
use crate::core::process_call_backs::SimpleCallback;

pub fn make_adventure_list(adventure_list: Vec<SimpleCallback>) -> HashMap<&i32, SimpleCallback> {
    let mut adventures = HashMap::new();

    let mut count = 1;

    for adventure in adventure_list {
        adventures.insert(count, adventure);

        count = count + 1;
    }

    adventures;
}
```

I get the error:

```
error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
 --> core/src/core/create_adventures.rs:5:76
  |
5 | pub fn make_adventure_list(adventure_list: Vec<SimpleCallback>) -> HashMap<&i32, SimpleCallback> {
  |                                                                            ^ help: consider giving it an explicit bounded or 'static lifetime: `&'static`
  |
  = help: this function's return type contains a borrowed value with an elided lifetime, but the lifetime cannot be derived from the arguments
```

I understand the meaning of this error, but not I'm sure how to implement the fix. Do I need to make `adventure_list` mutable?

Comment: The quick solution is to remove the `&` from `&i32`, you almost certainly want a 32 bit integer as your key, not a reference to a 32 bit integer.

Comment: Consider re-reading the relevant section of the book: [Chapter 4, What is Ownership?](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch04-01-what-is-ownership.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix a missing lifetime specifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43330616/how-do-i-fix-a-missing-lifetime-specifier)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want to map numbers to callbacks. But what you wrote is mapping *references to numbers* to callbacks.

Now, *references* have a lifetime. In your case, you start out with `count` - which lives only *inside your function*. Thus, even if you wanted to refer (i.e. have a reference) to it in your result, this would go wrong, as `count` goes out of scope at the end of the function.

What you almost certainly want, is your result type to be `HashMap<i32, SimpleCallback>`.

*Remark:* Since references have lifetimes, Rust suggests to add a `static` lifetime, meaning that you have references to numbers that are available for the whole run of the program (as opposed to only within your function). But, as said, you almost certainly do *not* want *references to* numbers, but simply numbers.